# Cannot Edit Vertices of Polyline Feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, vertices

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1. What I have is a single polyline feature for which I am trying to edit the vertices. The only thing check in my TOC is the shapefile I'm trying to edit, so there can't be anything else selected simultaneously. I can select the feature, but when I attempt to "Edit vertices," I get an error message telling me to "Select a single editable feature to modify." I have tried stopping and restarting editing sessions, both by selecting "Start editing" under the individual entry in my TOC and from the editor toolbar, with no difference. I could just be reasonable and create an entirely new feature; I see no reason why this should not be working, and it's driving me crazy. Can anyone shed any light on what might be happening here?

The feature selected with the drop-down menu enabled.
[image: The feature selected with the drop-down menu enabled.]

The error I get when I select "Edit vertices."
[image: The error I get when I select "Edit vertices."]

Comment: Great place to start would be the attributes table - the "feature" referred to by the error message are the features of the layer, not the layer itself.  Are there more than one rows in the attribute table selected?

Comment: I really don't know what the issue was, but it's working now. There was only one row in the attribute table, and I double checked to make sure nothing else was selected. I'm using an enterprise interface, so maybe it had something to do with a network drive? No idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a few different things, checking along the way, to see if it gets resolved...

1. Check to make sure that the line does not have a duplicate geometry.
2. Run ArcToolbox>Data Management Tools>Features>Repair Geometry.
3. Run the Multipart to Singlepart tool (same location as above) as a test - should not make a difference normally but might help whittle down the error.
4. Right click the layer of interest in the Table of Contents and go to Selection>Make This The Only Selectable Layer. Right click the map and choose clear selected features.

Comment: The line was hand-digitized, so there shouldn't have been any bad geometries. Like I said above, it's working now, so I really don't know what the issue was. Thanks for the advice, and I'll keep those in mind for any future issues I might have.